# Moving Median PostgreSQL with Partition

Tags: sql, postgresql, median, moving-average

I'm looking to create a prior rolling 4 quarter Median.  Some entries have less than 4 quarters, some have more.  I want this by Employee.  Needs to account for different tenure for different employees.

Result for 2021-1 should represent the prior 4 quarters median (and not account for current quarter).

I was able to figure out a rolling average with partitioning but not sure how to tackle a rolling median.

Thanks!

| Employee ID | Quarter | Sales | EXPECTED RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-1 | 1000 | NULL |
| A | 2020-2 | 2000 | 1000 |
| A | 2020-3 | 3000 | 1500 |
| A | 2020-4 | 4000 | 2000 |
| A | 2021-1 | 5000 | 2500 |
| A | 2021-2 | 4000 | 3500 |
| B | 2020-3 | 8000 | NULL |
| B | 2020-4 | 7000 | 8000 |
| B | 2021-1 | 6000 | 7500 |
| B | 2021-2 | 5000 | 7000 |
| B | 2021-3 | 1000 | 6500 |
| C | 2021-1 | 5000 | NULL |
| C | 2021-2 | 0 | 5000 |
| C | 2021-3 | 4000 | 2500 |

Comment: A median over 4 values?  That seems rather strange.  Why not just use the average?

Comment: @GordonLinoff To remove outliers or any quarters with 0 sales